# Como executar uma função em todos os arquivos PDF de um diretório sem especificar o nome, python!

Tags: python-3.x, estrutura-de-dados

Preciso coletar alguns dados de PDFs que surgem com nomes aleatórios e tenho que executar
a mesma função em todos os '.PDF' sem especificar o nome deles!

o código até então está assim:

```
import PyPDF2

pdf = open('850190086811.pdf', 'rb')
reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf)
pagina = reader.pages[0]
len(pagina.extract_text())
pedaço = pagina.extract_text()
pedaço.find('CNPJ')

print(pedaço[177:210])
```

eu consigo localizar o CNPJ desejado assim, mas preciso executar isso em sequencia e exibir resultado por resultado numa tabela/data frame/planilha/texto ou qualquer coisa que dê pra identificar os resultados

meu resultado é CNPJ/SEI: 03.480.652/0001-69

[link do pdf](https://we.tl/t-5Gw6Ik6DDw) que eu usei:

Comment: Você pode usar [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) ou [`pathlib.Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) para buscar arquivos, **a documentação já possui respostas** para as dúvidas mais comuns, recomendo que pesquise lá com calma e que de fato aprenda o básico antes de fazer o avançando e a documentação ajuda no passo a passo https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar a função `pathlib.Path.glob`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('.')
for file in path.glob('*.pdf'):
  with file.open() as pdf:
    ...
```

Isso percorrerá todos os PDFs do diretório atual, independente do nome.